# Oracle Database Change Notification JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Can I detect if there was an update in just 1 specific column of my table in Oracle? If so, how can I do it? I did a lot of research and I didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

You may enable Query Change Notification to get a notification when there is a committed change impacting the result set.
See the "ResultSets Caching with Change Notification - the Hard Way" section in this [blog post](https://medium.com/oracledevs/revisiting-java-applications-performance-scalability-with-rdbms-68d9f85466ca)